# Need Some MS Access Guideance

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
SELECT ID, OurMaps FROM tblMatterList where Matter_OpenDate=true and datestarted between dateadd("d", ([period]-1)*14,datevalue("01/01/" & year(date())) and dateadd("d", (([period]-1)*14)+14,datevalue("01/01/" & year(date()))
```

Does anyone know why this code isn't working, I keep getting a Compile Error: Expected: Case

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you add the surrounding code you're using?  Is this just in query design?  It is getting confused and looking for a Select Case structure.

Comment: it needs to be in ""

Comment: Your brackets are mismatching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a bracket from each of the dateadd functions, add one closing bracket after each:

```
year(date()))   <-- add another close bracket here
```